# Unstructured data into structured data using Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to structure the un-structured data using PIG for doing some processing.

Here's the sample of the data:

```
Nov 1   18:23:34    dev_id=03   user_id=000 int_ip=198.0.13.24  ext_ip=68.67.0.14   src_port=99 dest_port=213   response_code=5
```

**Expected output:**

```
Nov 1 18:23:34, 03 , 000, 198.0.13.24, 68.67.0.14, 99, 213, 5
```

As we can see data is not properly separated (like tab or comma), so i tried to load the data using '\t' and dumped on the terminal.

```
A = LOAD '----' using PigStorage('\t') as (mnth: chararray, day: int, --------);

dump A;

Store A into '\root\output';
```

**Output:**

**Dump output:**

```
(Nov,1,18:23:34,dev_id=03,user_id=000,int_ip=198.0.13.24,ext_ip=68.67.0.14,src_port=99,dest_port=213,response_code=5)
```

Store oputut:
Results are stored as the same as the input, not as dump(comma separated).

```
Nov 1   18:23:34    dev_id=03   user_id=000 int_ip=198.0.13.24  ext_ip=68.67.0.14   src_port=99 dest_port=213   response_code=5
```

Alternative: I also tried to load the data using DataStorage() as (value: varchar) and performed TOKENIZE also, but not able to achieve the objective.

Few more suggestion i need:

1. As i stored 3 fields as Month:"Nov", Day:"1", and Time:"18:23:34". Is it possible to join all three fields as time: "Nov 1 18:23:34".
2. All data stored with information like dev_id=03, user_id=000 but i need to remove the information and stored the information like 03,000,198.0.13.24 etc.

Is it possible to do all the processing using PIG or we need to write the MapReduce program.

### EDIT:1

After getting the comment, I tried REGEX_EXTRACT for single column which works fine. For multiple column, i tried REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL as follows:

```
A = LOAD '----' using PigStorage('\t') as (mnth: chararray, day: int, dev: chararray, user: chararray --------);

B = foreach A generate REGEX_EXTRACT_All(devid, userid, '(^.*=(.*)$) (^.*=(.*)$)');

Dump B;
```

I got error:

```
Error: ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve REGEX_EXTRACT_All using imports.
```

Can we extract multiple fields using REGEX_EXTRACT_All.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a custom loader for your data and all your issues will be solved easily with java.
Example of doing just that step by step can be found [here](http://arunxjacob.blogspot.com/2010/12/writing-custom-pig-loader.html)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Will try to write java program for customization.

Answer (score 0):

> As i stored 3 fields as Month:"Nov", Day:"1", and Time:"18:23:34". Is it possible to join all three fields as time: "Nov 1 18:23:34".

You can use [`CONCAT`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#concat) to concatenate two chararrays in a `FOREACH`. In this case (this is kind of awkward, perhaps someone can suggest an alternative that doesn't require a UDF):

```
CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(mnth, ' '), day), ' '), 'time')
```

---

> All data stored with information like dev_id=03, user_id=000 but i need to remove the information and stored the information like 03,000,198.0.13.24 etc.

You should use [`REGEX_EXTRACT`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#regex-extract) for this one, which extracts a piece of text given a regular expression. Use it in a `FOREACH`. Build a regular expression that grabs everything after the `=`. In this case:

```
REGEX_EXTRACT(field2, '^.*=(.*)$', 1);
```

---

Some other options:

- Writing your own custom Java storage function to do the parsing in java
- Write UDFs (python, java, whatever) to perform the above operations, instead of `REGEX_EXTRACT` and nested `CONCAT`.
- Load the line in its entirety as one chararray, then pass that into a UDF that does all the parsing, returning the result. This UDF gets put into a `FOREACH`. I like this better than writing a custom storage function, since I think it is a bit easier.
  *

Comment: Thanks @ Donald for sharing useful information. As i tried REGEX_EXTRACT for single column works fine. For multiple columns i tried REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(dev_id, user_id, int_ip, ext_ip, src, dest, response,  '^.*=(.*)$') but did not. Alternative i tired to load data as single field and then did tokenize, still getting error. I have added the explanation in question.

Comment: You have to do them separately. One `REGEX_EXTRACT` per column.

Comment: Is it not possible with multiple column? Built in function [REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#regex-extract). I tired to load all the sample data as chararray and then REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL('value', '(^.*=(.*)$');but got blank output.

Comment: No. That's just not how pig works. `REGEX_EXTRACT(field1, 'regex'), REGEX_EXTRACT(field2, 'regex'), ...`

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion, for single columns it works perfect. I need one more suggestion regarding joining the extracted fields. As we can extract the each field and stored in  A for field1 , B for field2 etc. How can we join all these fields, as for JOIN transformation we need one matched column but we have only one column in each field.

Comment: Can you use `CONCAT`?

Comment: Thanks I got all fields, i need one more suggestion. As i CONCAT(month,day,time) and stored into B. All REGEX_EXTRACT fields stored in C. As there is no matched column, Is there any merge or join procedure, so we can join B and C?